# Restrict reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, msbuild

Is it possible to make VS2013 csc or msbuild generate warning or an error if a project contains a code doing reflection?

This is meant as a defensive restriction against bad practices of our own developers (e.g. fresh graduates with no work experience or just a defense against a debugging code that definitelly shouldn't have been commited).

Comment: Would a static code analysis rule suffice?

Comment: I didn't know you could write these, I'll look on it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a pre/post-build step of grepping (findstr on Windows) for System.Reflection in all your source files. They'd either have to put it in a using statement or fully qualify the in-code usage so it would catch either case. Of course, it would potentially flag many false positives if you do have legitimate usages of System.Reflection in your code. The tricky part is inverting the return value of findstr (which usually returns 1 if it doesn't find the string). Try this:
`findstr /s /L "System.Reflection" *.cs && echo Error: using System.Reflection is not allowed. && set ERRORLEVEL=1 || set ERRORLEVEL=0` You can add more wildcards and/or make them more specific as needed.

Comment: You can do a fairly large amount of reflection without including the Reflection namespace. Also, `dynamic` is tantamount to reflection.

Comment: True. My idea would miss `var foo = bar.GetType().Assembly` which is pretty basic reflection. Catching that will require considerably more complicated rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe blanket ban on reflection.

However, you could use a custom task to achieve that, but this would be hard as it has to go through the source code to find where reflection is used and issue a warning.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx

Tools like FxCop, or Sonar might be able to help you with custom rules to analyze code.